# fluent validator in class library not work in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, validation, fluentvalidation

when i put fluent validators in asp.net core client side validation project exactly work
but when i put validator in class library not work

My model and validator in class library :

```
using FluentValidation;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Family { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
    public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
    {
        public PersonValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(c => c.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Name Is Empty");

        }
    }
}
```

In program.cs file :

```
services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation(M =>
{
    M.DisableDataAnnotationsValidation = true;
}).AddFluentValidationClientsideAdapters()
  .AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<PersonValidator>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

When the class library is nullable, the client-side validation in ASP.NET Core does not work.

Solution:

1. Remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from the `*.csproj`
2. Define nullable property:

   ```
   public string? name{get;set}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the issue, and it works in my side, I will show my test steps.

**Steps**

1. my project structure.

   [image]
2. The person.cs code same as yours

   [image]
3. The program.cs code same as yours

   [image]
4. My test method in Controller.

   ```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Test")]
    public IActionResult Test([FromBody]Person model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) //<----Validate here
        {
            return new BadRequestObjectResult(ModelState);
        }
        return Ok();
        //Other Code..
    }
   ```
5. Test result and it works.

   [image]